# Set the Search Filter to currency range

Tags: cpq

I have a requirement to create a Search filter with which the user can set a price range (currency field) to filter products in the Quote line editor.

I have already created the filter with the following config:
[image]

The problem is that it doesn't give me the ability the select a range ( which is available with date type fields).
How can I solve this.
thanks